# get php results with ajax json code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Hello this is my code to display data each 2s without refresh page but I don't know why it's not working.

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        done();
    });

    function done() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            updates();
            done();
        }, 2000);
    }

    function updates() {
        $.getJSON("saipa.php", function(data) {
                $("ul").empty();
                $.each(data.result, function(){
                    $("ul").append("<li>Name: "+this['Name']+"</li>
                         <li>detail: "+this['Description']+"</li>
                        <li>Today price: "+this['Today']+"</li>
                         <li>Last day price: "+this['Lastday']+"</li>
                        <br />");
                 });
             });
        }
    </script>
    <ul></ul>
</body>
```

**JSON:**

```
[{"Name":"arash","Description":"vian","Today":"20,500,000","Lastday":"22,410,000"},{"Name":"shaber","Description":"root","Today":"38,200,000","Lastday":"40,210,000"}]
```

Comment: `200` is not `2 seconds`

Comment: ok I fixed ...........................2000

Comment: Do you see any error in browser `console`?

Comment: try `$.each(data, ...)` instead of `$.each(data.result, ...)`

Comment: I use bu not working...

Comment: check browser `Console` **and** `Network` tab, do you see `saipa.php` being called many times or any errors.

Comment: **AND** `Network`? do you see `saipa.php` being call **many** times? or none at all?

Answer (score 0):

JSON cannot parse with `[]` use `.` operator
Try this code

```
function updates() {
     $.getJSON("saipa.php", function(data) {
       $("ul").empty();
       $.each(data, function(i,value){
        $("ul").append("<li>Name: "+value.Name+"</li>
                             <li>detail: "+value.Description+"</li>
                            <li>Today price: "+value.Today+"</li>
                            <li>Last day price: "+value.Lastday+"</li>
                            <br />");
       });
 });
}
```

Comment: No, that is not the issue

Comment: accessing Javascript object using `['name']` or `.name` are the same, and both valid

Answer (score 0):

Try using $.parseJSON(data)

```
  $.getJSON("saipa.php", function(data) {
                var data = $.parseJSON(data);
                $("ul").empty();
```

This function works good for timeouts as well.

https://gist.github.com/inceptzero/c391e7330c5b331ffa02

```
(function($){

    $(function(){  //document.ready

    });

    (function recurseEvent(element){

            element.doStuff();

            setTimeout(function(){
                recurseEvent(element);
            }, 2000);

    })($('#myElement'));

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: he did call again, function `done()` calls `done()` again